# Unauthorize Issue creating DiscoveryClient even with correct Credentials

Tags: c#, office365

My Problem is similiar to this Thread

[Unable to create Discovery Client object for Accessing Office365 calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018843/unable-to-create-discovery-client-object-for-accessing-office365-calendar)

I am 100% sure the client credentials are correct since i am getting an acces token but in the process of the DiscoveryClient i am receiving an *DiscoveryFailedException -> Uauthorized*

```
      public Uri discoverySer = new Uri("https://api.office.com/discovery/v1.0/me/");
   public string discoveryId = "https://api.office.com/discovery/";

   public string cmmAth = "https://login.windows.net/Common";


   public static AuthenticationContext _authenticationContext { get; set; }

   public string _settingCliID { get; set; }

   public string _settingCliSec {get; set; }

   public async void CreateClient()
   {
       NameValueCollection section = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings");
       _settingCliID = section["ida:ClientID"];
       _settingCliSec = section["ida:Password"];

       OutlookServicesClient outCli = await EnsureClientCreatedAsync();
       var eventResults = await outCli.Me.Events.ExecuteAsync();
   }


    public async Task<OutlookServicesClient> EnsureClientCreatedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            string authority = cmmAth;
            _authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            DiscoveryClient discoCli = new DiscoveryClient(discoverySer ,async () => await GetTokenHelperAsync(_authenticationContext, discoveryId));

            CapabilityDiscoveryResult discoResult = await discoCli.DiscoverCapabilityAsync("Calendar");
            var outlookCli = new OutlookServicesClient(discoResult.ServiceEndpointUri, async () => await GetTokenHelperAsync(_authenticationContext, discoResult.ServiceResourceId));
            return outlookCli;

        }
        catch (DiscoveryFailedException e)
        {
            if(_authenticationContext != null && _authenticationContext.TokenCache != null){
                _authenticationContext.TokenCache.Clear();
            }
            MessageBox.Show(e.Source);
            return null;
        }
        catch(AdalException e){
            MessageBox.Show(e.ErrorCode);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> GetTokenHelperAsync(AuthenticationContext context, string resourceId)
    {
        string accessToken = null;
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        ClientCredential cliCred = new ClientCredential(_settingCliID, _settingCliSec);
        result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, cliCred);
        accessToken = result.AccessToken;
        return accessToken;
    }
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Maciej

Comment: This is the response from Fiddler on DiscoveryClient step

{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}

Comment: Can you decode the token that you get back and see if it looks valid? https://github.com/jasonjoh/office365-azure-guides/blob/master/ValidatingYourToken.md

Comment: OK i am missing many key value pairs after the decode. So it is invalid but what can i do to make it valid

Comment: But you identify yourself as a User in your example i just only pass Client Credentials so actually its possible that this Token is valid

Comment: This is the result of it

 {
 typ: "JWT",
 alg: "RS256",
 x5t: "MnC_VZcATfM5pOYiJHMba9goEKY"
}.
{
 aud: "https://api.office.com/discovery/",
 iss: "https://sts.windows.net/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-xxxxxx/",
 iat: 1427204805,
 nbf: 1427204805,
 exp: 1427208705,
 ver: "1.0",
 tid: "f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-xxxxxx",
 idp: "https://sts.windows.net/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-xxxxxx/",
 appid: "b6f62f08-c066-4982-abf4-yyyyyy",
 appidacr: "1"
}.

Comment: When you say client credentials, are you referring to the client credential flow (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx)? Your token isn't valid if that's the case. You're missing the roles and oid claims, and your appidacr claim is set to 1, indicating you used a client id/secret instead of a certificate. Check that blog for details on how to do client credential flow. Also, you can skip discovery for Outlook, it will always be https://outlook.office365.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just confirmed with the Discovery API folks that it doesn't support client credentials, so that would explain it! As suggested in my comment, just skip discovery.

Comment: Ok after i changed the procedure to ClientAssertionCertificate i took some code from him and created the certificate. After i acquired the access token i tried to send a Httprequest but received a "{\"error\" : \"Forbidden\"}".

Comment: Yes, the Discovery API doesn't support client credential flow, even with a certificate.

Comment: ahh sorry my bad i forgot to mention i removed the Discovery api stuff you told me and i was referring to https://graph.windows.net/

Comment: Hey Jason, so I am having the same issue should I go ahead and use graph.  I am basically doing the Discovery client and passing in the me user assertion and getting unauthorized

Comment: I would move to Graph, yes.